# Login/logout button and text in navbar - conflict with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, navbar

I have a text and button on my index.html to check if someone is logged in and also so someone can check-out when logged in. So first there is always a text saying "not logged in" and when I log in, there is a logout button and when you press it you are being logged out. It works perfectly fine on the index page but I want to have it in my navbar next to the person icon but when I put it in the navbar it simply does not work. I figured out that it is because of a javascript interference, because my navbar is also loaded with javascript and jquery.There must be some way to say that my navbar should be loaded first and then the logout script or something.

this is my html for the index page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>guapo.</title>

    <link rel="icon" href="images/clementine.png" sizes="16x16 32x32" type="image/png" />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.js"
        integrity="sha256-nQLuAZGRRcILA+6dMBOvcRh5Pe310sBpanc6+QBmyVM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css" />
</head>

<body>

    <div id="navbar"></div>
    <p id="loggedInMessage">Not logged in</p>
    <div id="logoutContainer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" onclick="logout()">Logout</button>
    </div>
    <div class="container content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-5 col-sm-12" style="text-align:center; margin-top: 60px;">
                <h1 style="font-style: italic;">Where Green Dreams grow. <b> guapo. </b></h1>
                <h5 style="margin-top: 30px;">Willkommen in unserer Pflanzenwelt, in der jedes Blatt eine Geschichte von
                    Leben und Schönheit erzählt. Entdecken Sie unsere grüne Oase und holen Sie sich die Wunder der Natur
                    in Ihr Zuhause!</h5>
                <a href="alle-produkte.html"><button type="button" class="btn btn-light"
                        style="color: rgb(184, 107, 82); margin-top: 20px;">Alle Produkte</button></a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-7 col-sm-12" style="text-align: center;">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="images/plants.png" alt="illustration of plants"
                    style="width: 600px 100% \9;">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer"></div>
    <script src="./javascript/main.js"></script>
    <script src="./javascript/logout-login.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

this is my javascript for the logout function:

```
// Function to retrieve the JWT token from localStorage
        function getToken() {
            return localStorage.getItem("jwtToken");
        }

        // Function to check if the user is logged in
        function isLoggedIn() {
            const token = localStorage.getItem("jwtToken");
            return !!token; // Return true if a token exists, false otherwise
        }

        // Function to update the UI based on login status
        function updateUI() {
            const logoutContainer = document.getElementById("logoutContainer");
            if (isLoggedIn()) {
                // User is logged in, so show the logout button container
                logoutContainer.style.display = "block";
                loggedInMessage.style.display = "none";
            } else {
                // User is not logged in, so hide the logout button container
                logoutContainer.style.display = "none";
            }
        }

        // Call the updateUI function when the page loads
        window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
            updateUI();
        });

        // Rest of your code, including the logout function
        function logout() {
            // Remove the JWT token from local storage
            localStorage.removeItem("jwtToken");

            // Redirect the user to the login page
            window.location.href = '/Frontend/login.html';
        }

function logout() {
    // Remove the JWT token from local storage
    localStorage.removeItem("jwtToken");

    // Optionally, you can perform other cleanup tasks here
    // For example, redirect the user to the login page
    window.location.href = '/Frontend/login.html';
}
```

this is my navbar.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>navbar</title>

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.js"
        integrity="sha256-nQLuAZGRRcILA+6dMBOvcRh5Pe310sBpanc6+QBmyVM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark shadow p-3 mb-5 rounded">
        <div class="container">
            <a href="./index.html" class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1" style="font-size: x-large; color: cornsilk">guapo.
                <img class="d-inline-block align-top" src="images/clementine.png" width="38" height="38" />
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
                aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span><i id="menu-icon" class="bi bi-list"></i></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-between" id="navbarNav" style="color: cornsilk">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="gefilterte-produkte.html?category=pflanzen" class="nav-link active"
                            id="pflanzen">Pflanzen</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="gefilterte-produkte.html?category=toepfe" class="nav-link" id="toepfe">Töpfe</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="gefilterte-produkte.html?category=pflanzenfreunde" class="nav-link"
                            id="pflanzenfreunde">Pflanzenfreunde</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item me-3">
                        <a href="login.html" class="navbar-link">
                            <i class="bi bi-person-fill"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item me-3">
                        <a href="einkaufswagen.html" class="navbar-link">
                            <i class="bi bi-cart2"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
    </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

and this is how my navbar is loaded on every page:
`$("#navbar").load("../Frontend/navbar.html .navbar");`

I have tried a few codes or alternatives but nothing has worked so far.

Answer (score 0):

When you load an element into the DOM using jQuery it doesn't register the events in the same way that loading the HTML directly does.

Probably the easiest way to get around it is to register your click event to a parent element of the navbar, or even on the document itself.

```
$(document).on("click","#LogoutID",function() {
    logout()
});
```

Where #LogoutID is some valid selector for the element you want the tigger the logout function.

In a project of any sort of significant size it's probably preferable to investigate using a framework such as React, Vue, Angular etc which will help a lot with these kind of issues, and help avoid having code in the global javascript namespace as logout() currently appears to be.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite know where or how to implement this. Could you use the code I provided and implement it there? I don't really understand